# Can I change the license of a forked project to the MIT if the license of the parent project has changed from the GPL to the MIT?

Tags: mit, gpl-3, relicensing, forking

Some time ago I have forked a project on the GitHub that used the GNU GPL v3 license. So I also had to use the GPL license in my fork.

Recently, the author of the original project changed license to the MIT. Can I now change the license of my fork to the MIT too?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That depends.

If you didn't make any changes in your fork of the project, you can just update your fork to include the latest upstream changes and get the license change along with it.

If the copyrights on the changes made on your fork are all owned by you, and you agree with re-licensing those changes under the MIT license, then you can merge the upstream changes into your fork, including the license change.
If, as part of your changes, you added the use of a GPL-licensed library, then you can change the license of the code in your fork, but the combination with that external library would still be governed by the GPL license.

If you don't own all the copyrights on the changes in your fork, for example you accepted contributions from someone else or you re-used code written by another, then you must get approval from those others before you can incorporate the license change in your fork. As long as you don't have that approval, you must take care that you don't merge the upstream commits of the license change into (branches of) your fork that also contain GPL-licensed content for which you don't have permission to change the license.

Comment: Philosophical question: Is it a _fork_ if you never made any changes?

Comment: @pipe: Philosophically, no, but Github has muddled the meaning of the word "fork"...

Comment: @pipe A fork is a separate Github object. For instance, commits to one fork don't affect the other. The fact that they contain the same data doesn't mean they aren't different forks. In python, if you do `a = [1] b = a`, then `a` and `b` are the same object. If you do `a = [1] b= a.copy()` or `a= [1] b=[1]` then `a` and `b` are different objects, and `a is b` will return `False`.

Comment: It might be worth stating more clearly that OP may be required to re-fork their code from the current version, if the *previous version* still uses the *previous license*.  Possibly the license changed because the author deleted some code or dependency that required use of GNU GPL v3.